# List permissions of a folder for a specific user in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, permissions, active-directory, powershell-2.0, acl

I'm new to Powershell and I need to know how to list all permissions of a folder for a specific user. This is what I have discovered so far:

```
$ReferenceAccountName = 'DOMAIN\Username' 
[string[]]$SearchDirectories
= @('X:\SomeDirectory', 'F:\AnotherDirectory')

foreach ($RootDir in $SearchDirectories) {
    $DirACL = Get-Acl -Path $RootDir
    foreach ($ACL in $DirACL.Access){
        if ($ACL.IdentityReference -like $ReferenceAccountName){
            Write-Output $RootDir
        }
    }
    foreach ($Directory in (Get-ChildItem -Path $RootDir -Recurse | `
                            Where-Object -FilterScript {$_.Attributes `
                            -contains 'Directory'})){
        $DirACL = Get-Acl -Path $Directory.FullName
        foreach ($ACL in $DirACL.Access){
            if ($ACL.IdentityReference -like $ReferenceAccountName){
                Write-Output $Directory.FullName
            }
        }
    } }
```

However, this does not return any value with the Write-Output command. Changing it to Write-Host didn't work as well. Am I missing some crucial parts?

I'm using Powershell V2.0

Comment: Is it only one folder? So that you have one specific path to it? If yes, is this a shared folder or locally stored?

Comment: There is no difference. Tried it with a shared folder and with a local folder

Comment: take a look at my answer, should do it for you

Answer (score 1):

If I understood your question correctly, this should make it:

```
$user = "domain\username"
$path = "C:\Users\daisies"
$list = Get-ChildItem $path -Recurse | Where-Object {(Get-Acl $_.FullName).Access | Where-Object {$_.IdentityReference -eq $user} }
Write-Output $list
```

This outputs a list with your permission, LastWriteTime and filename.

Comment: This did indeed work. Thanks a lot. Would it also be able to exclude inherited permissions?

Comment: Hmm. It still has somer errors. The folders won't update if I change the permissions and rerun the command. Any idea why?

Comment: @Andr0mega I guess this a caching issue. The Information is cached and since you are not renewing the Variables, PS does not change anything. As you can see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14502611/does-powershell-have-a-cache-that-needs-to-be-cleared), you will need to add `Remove-Variable varname`